# Does DataSet.ReadXML() Validates the XML against the DTD

Tags: asp.net, xml, dataset

I have an xml file and I am loading it in DataTable using DataSet.ReadXML. This XML has an internal DTD Defined. I thought DataTable.ReadXML Validates an XML before loading it in memory. Is it the case ?

Do I need to set some property within my dataset to make it validate Xml against the DTD Defined or Do I need to validate it using some othe XML class

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>

<!DOCTYPE Resources [
<!ELEMENT Resources (Resource)+>
<!ELEMENT Resource (ResourceName,ResourceEmail)>
<!ELEMENT ResourceName (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ResourceEmail (#PCDATA)>

]>

<Resources>
<Resource>
<ResourceName>test</ResourceName>
<ResourceEmail>dfjfhg@fkjg.com</ResourceEmail>
</Resource>
</Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to validate your XML against a DTD

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
               settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
               settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;

               string data = null;
               XmlReader validatingReader = XmlReader.Create(File.Open("C:\\check\\TEMP_DTD.XML", FileMode.Open), settings, data);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(validatingReader);
```

Comment: if your XML is not defined as per DTD then line ds.ReadXml(validatingReader) will give an error

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the XmlReadMode enumeration with the ReadXML method:

```
DataSet.ReadXml(Stream|String|TextReader|XmlReader, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema)
```

e.g.

```
string xml = // your xml here; can also use Stream, TextReader or XmlReader

DataSet.ReadXml(xml, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
```

[DataSet.ReadXml Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml.aspx)

[XmlReadMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.xmlreadmode.aspx)

**EDITED TO ADD**

If you're looking to **validate** the XML, it appears you need to use XmlReader and create a "validating" reader.  Take a look at this post:

[DataSet does not validate XML Schema (XSD)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2010/04/02/dataset-does-not-validate-xml-schema-xsd.aspx)

Comment: :Can I use path of the xml File as well like :  ds.ReadXml("C:\\check\\TEMP_DTD.XML", XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);

Comment: @Sverma - I don't know why you wouldn't be able to.  Note a couple of things though - first, this works on DataSet, but DataTable doesn't appear to have an overload with the second option.  Two, I'm not entirely sure it will actually validate the XML as much as it will use the DTD to create the schema.

Comment: I just tried, If I use XMLReadMode.ReadSchema along with path of my xml file, I end up getting empty DataSet

Comment: It appears that the DataTable equivalent is [DataTable.ReadXmlSchema Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e982h2b.aspx), which would be called prior to the ReadXml.  Still thinking it won't do validation.

Comment: @Sverma - according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dywdff54.aspx), ReadXmlSchema is expecting an XSD, not an XML file with an inline DTD.

Comment: Thanks Tim for providing the link. But its pretty surprising that DataSet does not validate the xml

Answer (score 0):

```
        var errors = new StringBuilder();
        var isValid = true;
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += (o, e) => { errors.AppendLine(e.Message); isValid = false; };
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;


        var content = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" standalone=""yes""?>
                            <!DOCTYPE Resources [
                            <!ELEMENT Resources (Resource)+>
                            <!ELEMENT Resource (ResourceName,ResourceEmail)>
                            <!ELEMENT ResourceName (#PCDATA)>
                            <!ELEMENT ResourceEmail (#PCDATA)>                              
                            ]>                          
                        <Resources>
                            <Resource>
                                <ResourceName>test</ResourceName>
                                <ResourceEmail>dfjfhg@fkjg.com</ResourceEmail>

                                <YourPlaceIsNotHere>asdasd</YourPlaceIsNotHere>


                            </Resource>
                        </Resources>";
        using (var validator = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(content), settings))
        {
            while (validator.Read())
            {
                if (!isValid)
                {
                    validator.Close();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

A solution is to validate the xml before loading into a DataSet, using this code.